# How to combine two records to one with additional column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I run the query below

```
SELECT 
 ML.MemberID
,ML.effective_date
,CL.CaseID
,CL.CaseName
,CL.StartDate AS CaseCreatedDate    
,CONCAT(U.firstname,' ', U.lastname) AS PrimaryCaseOwner
,CONCAT(U2.firstname,' ', U2.lastname) AS SecondaryCaseOwner
FROM #MemberList ML
    INNER JOIN vw_CaseList CL 
        ON ML.member_id = CL.member_id
        AND CL.StartDate < GETDATE() 
        AND (CL.EndDate IS NULL OR CL.EndDate > GETDATE() )
    INNER JOIN Users U ON CL.primary_owner_id = U.[user_id]
    LEFT JOIN Cases_SecondaryOwners S ON CL.case_id = S.case_id
    LEFT JOIN Users U2 ON S.[user_id] = U2.[user_id] 
    where MemberID in ( 16468)  
ORDER BY MemberName, CaseCreatedDate
```

It returns this:

```
MemberID  :  Effective_Date : CaseID : CaseName : CaseDate : CaseOwner : 2nd Owner
45555          6/2/2019        0002     General   8/11/2019    John A.
45555          7/31/2019       0003     Special   9/1/2019     Jimmy       Tyler
45555          7/31/2019       0003     Special   9/1/2019     Jimmy       John A.
```

But I'd like to have the result like this:

```
MemberID  :  Effective_Date : CaseID : CaseName : CaseDate : CaseOwner : 2nd Owner1 : 2nd Owner2
45555          6/2/2019        0002     General   8/11/2019    John A.
45555          7/31/2019       0003     Special   9/1/2019     Jimmy       Tyler       John A.
```

How can I do that?
 Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you have a fourth owner, or a fifth? Can you guarantee it's only ever three as a maximum?

Comment: So far there are maximum two owners being entered by the business owners.   We will figure out if they want to enter more than 2.   Thanks~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT 
     ML.MemberID
    ,ML.effective_date
    ,CL.CaseID
    ,CL.CaseName
    ,CL.StartDate AS CaseCreatedDate    
    ,CONCAT(U.firstname,' ', U.lastname) AS PrimaryCaseOwner
    MIN(CONCAT(U2.firstname,' ', U2.lastname)) AS SecondaryCaseOwner1,
    CASE 
        WHEN MIN(U2.[user_id]) != MAX(U2.[user_id])
        THEN MAX(CONCAT(U2.firstname,' ', U2.lastname)) 
    END AS SecondaryCaseOwner2
FROM #MemberList ML
    INNER JOIN vw_CaseList CL 
        ON ML.member_id = CL.member_id
        AND CL.StartDate < GETDATE() 
        AND (CL.EndDate IS NULL OR CL.EndDate > GETDATE() )
    INNER JOIN Users U ON CL.primary_owner_id = U.[user_id]
    LEFT JOIN Cases_SecondaryOwners S ON CL.case_id = S.case_id
    LEFT JOIN Users U2 ON S.[user_id] = U2.[user_id] 
WHERE MemberID in = 16468
GROUP BY
     ML.MemberID
    ,ML.effective_date
    ,CL.CaseID
    ,CL.CaseName
    ,CL.StartDate AS CaseCreatedDate    
    ,U.firstname
    ,U.lastname
ORDER BY MemberName, CaseCreatedDate
```

Notes:

- this query makes sense only of there are no more than 2 secondary users; else, you will get the first and last user names, sorted by alphabetical full names
- I changed the condition in the `WHERE` clause from `MemberID in IN (16468)` to `MemberID in = 16468`; `IN` is better used when there are several elements in the list.